# In Google BigQuery API, what is the default timeout for a query response?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery API, what is the default timeout for a query response?

In other words, how long does it wait by default until the response returns null for an incomplete job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for [`timeoutMs`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#timeoutMs) in the `jobs.query` says:

> [Optional] How long to wait for the query to complete, in
>   milliseconds, before the request times out and returns. Note that this
>   is only a timeout for the request, not the query. If the query takes
>   longer to run than the timeout value, the call returns without any
>   results and with the 'jobComplete' flag set to false. You can call
>   GetQueryResults() to wait for the query to complete and read the
>   results. The default value is 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds).

If I understand correctly, though, I think you're asking how long a query can execute before timing out. We limit query execution to six hours (at the time of this writing), though I don't know if that's explicitly documented somewhere. In general, though, queries shouldn't take nearly that long to run.

If you want to impose a stricter timeout on query completion, you could use the [`jobs.cancel`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/cancel) API after a specific amount of elapsed time, though note that you will still be charged for execution of the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was looking for default wait time for timeoutMs, somehow missed it in the documentation. Thanks also for the other information about max query execution time.